# get the date difference for different format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is a simple question that how to get date different in javascript but my problem is that I store the date in database like `12-jan-2015`
so I don't know how to compare with other date and get the difference in days.

I tried many different ways as possible I know but still I don't get the right solution.

The last one I tried is below:

```
function ddiff() {
    var txtfromdate = document.getElementById('<%=txtPeriodFrom.ClientID%>').value;
    var txttodate = document.getElementById('<%=txtPeriodTo.ClientID%>').value;
    alert(txtfromdate);
    var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; //Convert into millisec
    var firstDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd-mm-yyyy", txtfromdate);
    var secondDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd-mm-yyyy", txttodate);
    alert(firstDate);          
    alert(secondDate);
    var noOfDays = Math.ceil((secondDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime()) / oneDay);
   return noOfDays;
}
```

However I don't get the last two alerts, so how can I get the difference in days?

Please help me, and thanks in advance...

Comment: *"However I don't get the last two alerts..."* Then you're getting an error. What is it?

Comment: seems your `$.datepicker` is not defined or your  `jquery` not loaded...

Comment: Timestamp: 6/17/2015 5:10:40 PM
Error: TypeError: date.getDate is not a function

Comment: Note that you don't need to change the format of the date strings - the `Date()` object will read `dd-MMM-yyyy` fine. From there you can use the exact same logic as the duplicate question which I linked to.

Comment: Timestamp: 6/17/2015 5:46:15 PM
Error: TypeError: txttodate.getTime is not a function  again same error

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting that. Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ud6ct65g/

Comment: there i also got the same answer like Nan